# selben inflected or uninflected

Tags: grammar-identification

The form selbe is used after:

```
contractions of a preposition and the definite article:
am selben Ort        (but: an demselben Ort)    
im selben Team       (but: in demselben Team)   
vom selben Bäcker    (but: von demselben Bäcker)    
zur selben Zeit      (but: zu derselben Zeit)   

demonstrative pronouns:
diese selben Worte
an diesem selben Ort
in jener selben Nacht
```

http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-dieser-jener3.html?MenuId=Word4241&lang=en *"the given link doesn't properly working here it link to dieser instead of derselbe"*

In the given examples whether the selbe used in a inflected manner or is it a noninflected a "selben"? because there is only "selben" and not any other inflected form. If it is inflected form then can I write following

> fürs selbe Team or für dasselbe Team

and

> dieses selbe Team

Answer (score 2):

*Selbe* is inflected like a weak adjective. See the [declension table](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Demonstrativpronomen_derselbe).

In the weak declension, most forms end with -en. That's why all the examples have this ending.

*Selbe* is weak because there is always an article or a demonstrative pronoun (which qualifies as an article word [*Artikelwort*]) before it.